# Is there a way to have SSMS open a certain connections every time I open it up?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ide, ssms

Every night the university reboots every machine in my department at midnight and I help my professor with various projects on 11 different sql servers.  Since i do not own a personal computer i can't just leave SSMS open over night.

Is it possible to have a setting or some featured enabled so that it remembers to open the connections that i tell it to when i open SSMS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call SSMS from the command line and uses switches to do what you're trying to do.

There are -S -d -U and -P switches for server, database, username, and password. You should be able to put the call into a .bat file and use that easily enough.

There is [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162825.aspx) on the Microsoft website.

Comment: thank you for this, i have ran this from teh cmd but i get ssms not recognized as a command...i wonder if i need to reinstall ssms

Comment: oops, i am a fool, please disregard taht above comment i could get to it like thsi: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to install third party software the [SSMS Tools Pack addin](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features#QEH) does what you need.

> ... You can also Restore Last Session by pressing the button on
>   toolbar. This opens the last saved tabs already connected to the
>   server they were connected to before...